# 93 chevy c1500 4.3L electric window moves freely

Tags: chevrolet, maintenance, power-windows

Brand new switch on driver side window mechanism but window no longer works when switch is pressed but rolls freely up and down by hand.

Opened up door panel and found motor mechanism just laying at the bottom of my door.

First question is what's going on?

Second is can I just put it back on?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you upload a picture of what you're seeing? That should help us point you in the right direction

Comment: Is the power still connected to the window motor and does the window motor still turn as it should (even though it's not connected to the regulator) when you press the buttons? What happened to the bolts to the regulator? Did they come lose or did the motor bust free of its moorings?

Comment: Nothing happens but I haven't checked the wiring yet I'm gonna go in there and clean everything. So can it be just put back in? I have to slam my door pretty hard cuz door latch doesn't catch all the way most the time so it might explain why it looks like it just tell out

Answer (score 2):

You mention having a bad door latch and having to slam the door. :)

Here is what I would do:

1. Remove interior panel.
2. Fish out all of the loose parts. Including bolts/nuts in the bottom.
3. With the window all the way up (fully closed) try and mount the motor in place.
4. Bolt it in.
5. Turn the ignition switch on and test it.
6. Pay attention to the motor *and* regulator (the part that raises the window itself).

Did the motor move but the window did not?

Check the connection between the motor and regulator. A bad coupling means the motor spins but does not engage.

Check the regulator rails and cables. Are they bent? Broken?

Did the motor not move?

Check you are getting current at the motor connector by hitting the switch with the key in the on position and measuring volts with a multimeter. Anything less than 11.5V means the switch, relay or wiring is/are bad.

Go through the circuit with the volt meter. You will find the issue.

What if the regulator is bad?

Simply remove the window and place it somewhere safe (dont lay it down because it increases the chances of someone stepping on it).

Remove the regulator and install a new one.

Re-connect the rest of the parts.

Good luck!